# Enviromental value not working in .js file / Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js, environment-variables

I have an app that I am testing, it has a widget that requires an api key within a script that has to be placed in my  tags, so my .js file is inside my public folder and is being import to my layout.tsx as so:

```
 <html lang="en">       
    <Script src="crm.js"/>
    <body>
```

I have created an .env.local file and place my varibale as so:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_META_CRM_API_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxx
```

I have my variable inside my .js file like so:

```
 MetaCRMWidget.init({
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_META_CRM_API_KEY
  });
```

My widget fails to load with no authorisation but when I enter the apikey directly into my script it works.

I am trying to test this locally.

Images of errors when adding process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_META_CRM_API_KEY[image]:

Comment: Where this MetaCRMWidget.init is called? In whic file/folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Next.js documentation found [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#bundling-environment-variables-for-the-browser), it is not possible to read process.env directly from an .js file. At build time Next transforms your process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_META_CRM_API_KEY to the real value. As you are loading this script from a script tag, I think Next is not transforming the value, also seen by the error `process is not defined` in the console. As you are exposing this value publicly, it is not a secret, so try inputting your API key directly in the widget init code.

Like this:

```
MetaCRMWidget.init({
    apiKey: "your api key"
  });
```

Comment: Hey I did change this and didnt realise the mistake in my post. It was correct in my code. I have posted a new image above of my console errors. Its strange because when i console.log the key in one of my components it shows correct value, but when i place the process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_META_CRM_API_KEY in my js file it does not seem to like it.